# Customize Cast Remote Display Session on Android

Tags: android, ios, resolution, google-cast, frame-rate

I am developing an app using the Google Cast Remote Display APIs on Android.
Everything works quite well, but the video quality that is sent to the TV screen is really bad.
I would like to configure the video parameters of TV image such as framerate, resolution, etc...

Using the iOS SDK, it seems to be possible (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote#start-a-remote-display-session) but looking everywhere in the Android SDK I didn't manage to find how to do that.

The only thing I found is to use `CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.startServiceWithOptions`, building a `CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.Options` object, and calling the `.setConfigPreset` method with `CastRemoteDisplay.CONFIGURATION_NONINTERACTIVE` or `CastRemoteDisplay.CONFIGURATION_INTERACTIVE_NONREALTIME` or `CastRemoteDisplay.CONFIGURATION_INTERACTIVE_REALTIME` as parameter.

But nothing more detailed where I could set up my own framerate, resolution or even video codec?

Does someone succeed in doing this ?

Kind regards,

jn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those parameters are not configurable by developers.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your answer. Do you agree that these parameters are configurable with the iOS SDK ? I am really wondering why it would be available for iOS and not Android.